# how to do replace and explode for array input in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, string, laravel, postman

I am beginner to laravel. I am trying to access array input from my API request.

For postman, I have array as key called `file_name_list` and its value like `["m_profile.png","aa_image.jpg","new_pan.jpg"]`. I want to access that array in my controller. That values should go into 3 seperate variables like

```
$profile = m_profile.png 

$aadhar = aa_image.jpg

$pan = new_pan.jpg
```

For that I am trying to use replace and explode functions in controller.

```
$filenamelist1 =  Str::replaceArray(array(' ','"', '[',']'),[""], $request->file_name_list);
$filename_str = explode(",",$filenamelist1);
```

After this I want to store values from `explode` array to 3 variables as mentioned above using `for loop`

But I am facing problems like in `Str::replaceArray` 2 parameter should be array and for `explode` 2 parameter should be string.

How should I use replace and explode to get required result? please guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like a JSON array, so `$filename_str = json_decode($request->file_name_list, true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `list` method like below:

```
list( $profile , $adhar, $pan) = $request->file_name_list;
```

Check the [Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$value  = '["m_profile.png","aa_image.jpg","new_pan.jpg"]';
$value  = str_replace("[","",$value);  // clean [
$value  = str_replace("]","",$value); // clean ]
$arrayValues = explode('","',$value);  // explode with ","

print_r($arrayValues);
```

output

```
Array (
    [0] => "m_profile.png
    [1] => aa_image.jpg
    [2] => new_pan.jpg"
)
```

Replace `"` when you access the values

Answer (score 0):

If Your array size fixed then you assign that by using list

```
list( $profile,$adhar,$pan) = $request->file_name_list;
```

Comment: what if my array size is not fixed? what is the solution available in laravel?